# ASP Web API, C#: Как в Контроллере узнать URL, с которого был вызван этот контроллер?

Tags: c#, маршрутизация, asp.net-web-api

Как узнать URL (например: `HttpRequest.UrlReferrer`) с которого был совершен вызов?

Я побовал так:

```
var refUrl1 = ((System.Web.HttpContextWrapper)Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).ApplicationInstance.Request.UrlReferrer;
var refUrl2 = Request.Headers.Referrer;
```

Но результат тут null.

Как правильно я узнать тот URL ?

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri` ?

Comment: @tym32167  HttpContext это же тип, а не статический класс; ругается на HttpContext , не знает, что это такое

Comment: [HttpContext.Current Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.current?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @tym32167 а что делать если System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer все равно null? может есть еще способ?

Comment: может есть, но я уже много лет не писал бекенд, потому на память не вспомню

Comment: @tym32167 ок, спасибо

Comment: Для начала нужно убедиться, отправляет ли клиент Referrer. Использовать его нужно не как ограничительную меру (например запрещать если Referrer не со своих ресурсов) а как информационную (например для статистики), потому как Referrer может блокироваться чем угодно.

Answer (score 0):

Если `HttpRequest.UrlReferrer = null`,  правильный ответ - никак.

УРЛ, который я хотел получить, должен прийти в заголовке или теле запроса

Comment: Надо через Fiddler, например, посмотреть - что вообще приходит с клиента. Если клиент не отправляет Referer, то ничего не удастся с этим сделать, конечно.